# Best/Secure Windows 2008 Server transfer protocol

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, sftp, protocol

I hate FTP because it is not secure, passwords are cleartext, etc. I want something safe for my windows server and I used to use sftp on linux for a while but now I turned to windows solution so I'm a bit of a newbie about it.

I'd like to know, what's the best and or most secure solution for transering file to my server? I'll be the only one transfering files to it so I don't really care about user quotas etc.

I just want a secure and stable connection to my server so I can easily and rapidly transfer files. (I use web deploy for visual studio projects hosting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is still no SFTP build in but there is  "[FTP Publishing Service](http://www.iis.net/download/FTP)" for IIS 7 which can do it.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using IPSEC. It a bit of an off-the-wall suggestion, I know, but assuming your server has a static IP address it would be fairly simple to setup a pre-shared key in your client's IPSEC policy that would encrypt all communication to the server transparently. At that point you don't really need to worry about what file transfer mechanisms you use since any communication between your client and the server computer will be encrypted. Being transparent to the application layer would, I think, be advantageous.

You could accomplish something similar using a VPN (OpenVPN, SSTP, etc), but using the built-in IPSEC functionality would be transparent (no VPN to "connect").

Answer (score 1):

No one mentioned filezilla ftp server. It supports FTP over SSL/TLS. You can encrypt both auth phase and/or data transfers. Filezilla server creates self-signed certificates, making it ready to be used in a couple of minutes after installing it.

Read its features list.

Answer (score 0):

We use [CopSSh](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh) which is a windows build of the open source SSHd service.  Besides that, as duenni says, IIS 7 supports FTP over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use either a VPN or RPD and check one of your local drives. Then you can transfer securely local drive to the server (you will see your local drive in the server's "My Computer".